# How to underline a word in parentheses in org-mode to export to LaTeX

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to underline a word in parentheses to export to LaTeX.  I used (_word_) in the org-mode file but the LaTeX output produced is (\_word\_) and in the resulting pdf file I just get (_word_).  Can anyone advise me how to get what I want?

Comment: If you can live with it, the easiest workaround is to add spaces: `( _word_ )`. Actually, you only have to add a space between the opening paren and the underscore, but the output looks funny to me, so I like to add one at the beginning and one at the end.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  That was one of the options I tried.  My final solution was to just edit and compile the LaTeX file to produce the pdf.

Comment: The only trouble with this is that if you ever export the file again, you will have to do it all over again.

Answer (score 3):

For me it looks like a bug in OrgMode. For me,

```
this is (_underline_) text. another _underline_ text
```

produce following result:

[image: screenshot]

I recommend to file a bug against OrgMode

Comment: It probably will not be accepted: an underscore without a space before it is interpreted as the start of a subscript, which is why you get what you get. You can stop org from interpreting like that with `#+OPTIONS: ^:nil ` or perhaps better `#+OPTIONS: ^:{}` (the latter says "interpret underscore as a signal to subscript but only if the subscript is surrounded by braces". However, you still don't get an underlined word inside the parens, but that's a different story: search for "emphasis" in the mailing list for the gory details.

Comment: BTW,  the OP must be using one of the OPTIONS above: the latex output is exactly what he reports in that case.

Comment: Thank you for comments Nick - maybe it's better that you answer?

Comment: If I had a good solution I would, but I don't: emphasis has been a thorn on org-mode's side for a long time, with no solution in sight.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug of org-mode introduced in version 8.

The latest version (based on version number) of org-mode without this bug is 8.0-alpha.

The latest version (based on commit date) of org-mode wihtout this bug is 7.9.4.

Minimal working examples follow.

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil

a_5

( _test_)
(_test_)
```

Under both version 7.9.4 and 8.0-alpha, the output is correct as shown belew.

[image: Version 7.9.4 with correct underline]

[image: Version 8.0-alpha with correct underline]

But under version 8.0-beta and onward, the output is incorrect.

[image: Version 8.0-beta with incorrect result]

Comment: Many thanks Lei.  You're right.  I'm using version 9.0.9 (with Ubuntu 17.10) and have just revisited my document.  The error is still there.

Comment: To save people re-running the test - Emacs 26.1 (Org mode 9.1.13) still shows the same issue.